# Crontab - don't log? How can I do it right?

Tags: cron, log, autostart, logging

I've search for a answer of my problem but I can't find the right one. So I try it my self.

I've got an Ubuntu Server and try to create a TeamSpeak3 Server - check file with loggin function. This script should be auto startet by a cronjob every hour.

My check-script (selfcheck.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/teamspeak/s01
LOGFILE='/home/teamspeak/s01/mylog.selfcheck'

function logg(){
        echo -n `date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` >>$LOGFILE
        echo " | `basename $0` $1" >>$LOGFILE
}


#COMMANDLINE_PARAMETERS="${1}" #add any command line parameters you want to pass here
DIR=/home/teamspeak/s01/
USER=teamspeak

logg "### GESTARTET ###"

if [ -e ts3server.pid ]; then
    if ( kill -0 $(cat ts3server.pid) 2> /dev/null ); then
        echo ""
        echo "      ###################"
        echo "      #Server is running#"
        echo "      ###################"
        echo ""
        status=1

        echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | Server is running" >>$LOGFILE

    else
        echo ""
        echo "      ###########################"
        echo "      #Server seems to have died#"
        echo "      ###########################"
        echo ""
        status=2

        echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | Server seems to have died" >>$LOGFILE

    fi
else
    echo ""
    echo "      ##########################"
    echo "      #The server isn't running#"
    echo "      ##########################"
    echo ""
    status=3

    echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | The server isn't running" >>$LOGFILE

fi

if [ $status = "2" ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "      ##############"
    echo "      #Status ist "$status"#"
    echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | Status ist "$status >>LOGFILE
    echo "      ###RE-START###"
    echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | RE-START" >>LOGFILE
    echo "      ##############"
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo "      ######################"
    echo "      #Stopping the Server!#"
    echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | Stopping the Server!" >>LOGFILE
    echo "      ######################"
    echo ""
    ./ts3server_startscript.sh stop inifile=ts3server.ini
    echo ""
    echo "      ######################"
    echo "      #Starting the Server!#"
    echo "`date +\%d.\%m.\%Y` `date +\%H:\%M:\%S` | Starting the Server!" >>LOGFILE
    echo "      ######################"
    echo ""
    ./ts3server_startscript.sh start inifile=ts3server.ini


fi

logg "###  BEENDET  ###"

exit 0
```

Now my crontab entry:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  */1 *   *   *   *    /home/teamspeak/s01/selfchek.sh >> /home/teamspeak/s01/cronlog
```

This crontab is loading but there is no output in the "cronlog" file. It's empty. Also there is no output to my "mylog.selfcheck".
But if I execute the script (selfcheck.sh) manually there is an output to "mylog.selfchek".

I'm sorry for my bad language....you konw this sentence...

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you set cron `*/1 * * * *` cron will run every min. Set cron `* */1 * * *` to run on hour.

Restart cron, after editing

```
sudo service cron restart
```

To check how cron work run

```
crontab -l | grep -v '^#' | cut -f 6- -d ' ' | while read CMD; do eval $CMD; done
```

Like you known log can check on

```
less /var/log/syslog | grep cron
```

Edit 1

Based on your comment cron work. Also you say, when you run script you have output in defined log file `LOGFILE='/home/teamspeak/s01/mylog.selfcheck'` in script. Ok.

You wont to the same content from `mylog.selfcheck` in `cronlog`.
Then set cron, as you already, to run script `selfchek.sh` and add
second command in cron to put content from `mylog.selfcheck` to `cronlog`

```
 * */1 * * * cat /home/teamspeak/s01/mylog.selfcheck >> /home/teamspeak/s01/cronlog
```

Final cron code

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * */1 * * *    /home/teamspeak/s01/selfchek.sh
  * */1 * * *    cat /home/teamspeak/s01/mylog.selfcheck >> /home/teamspeak/s01/cronlog
```

Comment: teamspeak@Ubuntu-1410-utopic-64-minimal:~/s01$ crontab -l | grep -v '^#' | cut -f 6- -d ' ' | while read CMD; do eval $CMD; done

CHANGELOG: command not found
This is what I get.
//I set it to every minute just to test the loggoing.

Comment: May 28 06:29:02 Ubuntu-1410-utopic-64-minimal CRON[19365]: (teamspeak) CMD (/home/teamspeak/s01/selfchek.sh >> /home/teamspeak/s01/cronlog )

Comment: In the second comment i've copy the "less /var/log/syslog | grep cron" output.

Comment: You have my edit 1

Comment: Well thanks for your help. But the logging prozess in my selfsheck.sh script does only work if I execute it manually. But not by cron.

Comment: Only when I can propose is to run `cron` like user, not like `root`. Put rules in `cron` with this command `crontab -u username -e`. Username is, i guess, `teamspeak`.